# Why should I use data contracts instead of parameters for WCF service calls?

Tags: wcf

Why should I use data contracts instead of parameters for WCF service method calls?

Comment: Your question is not very descriptive. Please provide more details, probably with a code example.

Comment: It is intentionally general and I don't have associated code. Just looking for some pros/cons to using data contracts for passing data to a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using DataContracts *instead* of parameters.... if your parameters are atomic types, like `string` and `int`, you don't need data contracts on these.

But if you create a compound type, which is often beneficial is you have five or more parameters, then you need to decorate that class type with `[DataContract]` to make it clear to WCF that that's the class you want to use and serialize.

Having two, three simple parameters is great - but as soon as you have more than that, or if you need to pass back more than a single value, you typically should use a class to group/hold those values together.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataContract` is just an attribute which is used to decorate the classes you will be using as parameters to your service methods. Starting from .NET 3.5 SP1 you no longer need to decorate your objects with DataContract/DataMember attributes, all public properties will be automatically serialized.